# Query Firebase Firestore documents by the ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As I got from 'Cloud Firestore Data Model' guide "each document is identified by a name." Is it possible to query a collection by that document identifier (which is the name or ID)?

For example, documents in the collection "Things" have IDs: 0, 1, 2 etc.:

[image]

Is it possible to query documents which IDs are less than 100?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can query by documentId using the special sentinel `FieldPath.documentId()`, e.g.:

```
const querySnap = collection.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<', '100').get();
```

But be aware that document IDs are *strings* and therefore this will include documents with ID '0' or '1', but not '2' since '2' > '100' lexicographically.

So if you want a numeric query, you'll need to write the document ID as a numeric field in the document and then do a normal query on it.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for python? I could not find it!

Comment: @AníbalRivero It might not be implemented yet. You may want to open an issue on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues

Comment: Any idea if this is possible inside `firebaseConnect` using [`react-redux-firebase`](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase)?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher have you found any way to do that?

Comment: Angular - make sure to ```import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';```

Comment: @AníbalRivero they added the python equivalent, still testing...
google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path.FieldPath.document_id()

Comment: The equivalent for (firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()) in Python is to simply mention the static value directly => `__name__` [Source: /google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py]

Answer (score 18):

In python, you should use full documents names

```py
from google.cloud import firestore
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path import FieldPath

db = firestore.Client()
colRef = db.collection(u'docs')
filter = [db.document(u'docs/doc1'), db.collection(u'docs/doc3')]
query = colRef.where(FieldPath.document_id(), u'in', filter)
```

Comment: Solved my problem. This usage seems not documented elsewhere.

Comment: Note: the `in` filter only accepts a maximum of 10 entries before throwing an error, so be ready if you have this in production code...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to find this for the Golang Firebase SDK but finally got it. Hope this helps somebody out there!

```
package main
    
import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "log"

  "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
  firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
  "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

type (
  Car struct {
    ID    string
    Name  string  `firestore:"name"`
    Make  string  `firestore:"make"`
    Price float64 `firestore:"make"`
  }
)

func main() {
  ctx := context.Background()

  // Use a service account
  options := option.WithCredentialsFile("PATH/TO/SERVICE/FILE.json")

  // Set project id
  conf := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "PROJECT_NAME"}

  // Initialize app
  app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf, options)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  // Get firestore client
  client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer client.Close()

  collectionRef := client.Collection("CAR_COLLECTION")
  
  // Create docment list of documents from "CAR_COLLECTION"
  var skipDocs []*firestore.DocumentRef
  idList := []string{"001", "002", "003"}
  for _, id := range idList {
    skipDocs = append(skipDocs, collectionRef.Doc(id))
  }

  // firestore.DocumentID == "__name__" 
  docs, err := collectionRef.Where(firestore.DocumentID, "not-in", skipDocs).Documents(ctx).GetAll()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  var carList []Car
  for _, doc := range docs {
    var car Car

    // Unmarshall item
    doc.DataTo(&car)
    car.ID = doc.Ref.ID

    // Add car to list
    carList = append(carList, car)
  }

  // Print car list
  fmt.Println(carList)
}
```