# How to write a where clause on the document's ID we want on a Query object, in Java?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'd want to write something like that:

```
public Query getQueryToNotDeletedUsers(String user_id) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").whereEqualTo("deleted", false).whereEqualTo("ID", user_id);
}
```

As you can see, I can't just write something like `.document(the_id)` since I use a `Query object` (the `where` call).

I've already seen some answers to this question, but not in Java. Indeed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264/6500085
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467056/6500085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android that would be `FieldPath.documentId()`:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), user_id).whereEqualTo("deleted", false)
```

See the [Firebase reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath.html#documentId()). I highly recommend keeping the (reference) documentation handy, as this is a quite literal translation of the JavaScript code in the questions you linked.