# Firestore pagination: how to query last page

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created an public restful POST api for searching using Firebase function and firestore:

```
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { eventIds, queryString, startAtIndex, limit } = req.body;
    let query = firestore()
        .collection("IndexedEcImage_test")
        .where("eventId", 'in', eventIds);

    if (queryString) {
        query = query.where("generatedSearchKeys", "array-contains", queryString);
    }

    query = query.orderBy("timestamp")

    if (startAtIndex) {
        query = query.startAfter(startAtIndex);
    }

    const snapshot = await query.limit(limit).get();
    const results = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    res.status(200).send({
        indexForNextPage: results[results.length - 1].timestamp,
        data: results
    });
});
```

The body request:

```
{
    "eventIds": [
        "9m6k89aOlqeXpaJ3oZhW1"
    ],
    "queryString": "ABC",
    "startAtIndex": 1637128385472,
    "limit": 2
}
```

The output is like this:
{
"indexForNextPage": 1637128385472,
"data": [{...},{....}]
}

For example: The "IndexedEcImage_test" collection has 5 docs. I expected that the pagination would be like that:

Page 1: first 2 docs  =>   Page 2: next 2 docs  => Last page: the last doc

The indexForNextPage in the output is used to fetch the next page, but when it comes to the last page, it gave me a timeout. I guess the limit goes beyond the number of the remaining docs. The number of remaining docs can change differently depending on the total docs or the limit. Is there a general way to fetch the last page without counting all the docs?

Answer (score -1):

I will start by recommending you read this [note](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#modular-version) and the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade). In case you might be using an old tutorial and you have accidentally merged the two versions, it's a common mistake that could cause issues. If that is not the case,  and you are opting to use the 8 version I found two old questions using that SDK version that might help you.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674125/firestore-pagination-previous) one, the advice is...

> To detect whether there are more pages to load, you'll need to request an additional item. So, since you seem to show 2 items per page, you have to request 3 items - and display only two of them. If you get a third item, you know there's an additional page.

and the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674125/firestore-pagination-previous) contains this piece of code that in my opinion could be useful:

> ```js
> $("#js-previous").on('click', function () {
>    $('#employee-table tbody').html('');
>    var previous = db.collection("employees")
>        .endBefore(firstVisible)
>        .limitToLast(3);
>    previous.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
>        documentSnapshots.docs.forEach(doc => {
>            renderEmployee(doc);
>        });
>    });
> });
> ```

---

However, if you consider using the latest version 9 SDK, once you have made a migration this would be a suggested  way of [Paginate a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) to get the last document in a batch. You can compare this to the 8 SDK version and see the differences on the code they use to get the last element:

> ```js
> var first = db.collection("cities")
>         .orderBy("population")
>         .limit(25);
>
> return first.get().then((documentSnapshots) => {   // Get the last visible document   
> var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];  
> console.log("last", lastVisible);
>
>   // Construct a new query starting at this document,   
>   // get the next 25 cities.   
> var next = db.collection("cities")
>           .orderBy("population")
>           .startAfter(lastVisible)
>           .limit(25); 
>  });
> ```

Note: All the code samples are using version 8 of the sdk

The video in the same page is very informative and can be very useful to understand how pagination works.

Comment: the code shows how to query the next page, not the last page of, for example, 1000 pages, so this is answering the wrong question