# Firestore query: How to filter on document id?

Tags: firebase

In Firestore, I have a collection containing documents identified by timestamp: `/records/timestamp`
I would like to filter documents based on the id, using the javascript client API.
How can I write the query?
I am looking for something along the following line, but I cannot find the proper field name for *id*:

```
const query = firestore.collection(`/records`).where("id", "<", 1600766222);
```

Comment: I would recommend saving the timestamp as a field as you would be able to order it and also store it as a number. But if you really need the string ID for other purposes, us FieldPath.documentId().

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When you mention ordering, don't you think it is possible to do ```query.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId())``` ?

Comment: Yes Louis but this will order it the way strings are ordered. I suppose you'll want to arrange according to the order they came and not the order of their string values (ASCII VALUES). And in the future when you have a lot of data, you may want to add a new feature which uses timestamps as a number and it will be a headache to fix then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible using FieldPath.documentId(), but there are limitations.

```
db.collection('CollectionName').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<', '100').get()
```

But be aware that document IDs are strings and therefore this will include documents with ID '0' or '1', but not '2' since '2' > '100' lexicographically.

So if you want a numeric query, you'll need to write the document ID as a numeric field in the document and then do a normal query on it.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467056/1212903

Comment: Perfect! I will stick to using the document id instead of a field because I am fine with lexicographical ordering as I deal with timestamps exclusively. Would you do otherwise?