# Firestore: get document by ID from CollectionGroup

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a snapshot of a `Book` by its document ID.

My structure looks like this:

```
           stores
          /      \
    Store1        Store2
      |               |
    books            books
    /   \           /  |  \
 Book1 Book2   Book3 Book4 Book5
```

(`stores` is a collection)

I tried with a collection group:

```
my_id = "XXXYYYZZZ" # I know that there is a book with this ID
firestore.Client.collection_group('books').where('id', "==", my_id)
```

But it looks for `id` field instead of document ID.

I tried also to read all `Book` documents and filter by ID in Python, but I have maaany books, so that's not an option.

```
books = firestore.Client.collection_group('books').get()
book = [b.id for b in books if b.id == my_id]
```

And I cannot define a specific path to the document, because I have multiple stores.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

for python:

```
db.collection.where(filter=FieldFilter('__name__', '==', doc_ref))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to query for a document ID, you can use the [`FieldPath.document_id()` operator](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path.FieldPath#google_cloud_firestore_v1_field_path_FieldPath_document_id).

So that'd look something like (not a Pythonista here):

```
.where(FieldPath.document_id(), "==", my_id)
```

Also see:

- [Query Firebase Firestore documents by the ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63803724/209103)

Comment: hm, it doesn't seem to work... I'm printing my collection group and there is my `Book`, but filtering it with what you suggested gives me nothing :( In the answer you linked there's not a comparison to a string (like in my case), but to a document or a collection...

Comment: Given this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150650/4034593 I don't think that's possible, what I'm trying to do :( I think that's crucial that I'm working with collection group, not a single collection.

Comment: Aha, right... I forgot that in collection group indexes the `documentId` actually contains the entire path of the document (as the document ID alone might not be unique). In that case I don't think it is possible to query this way, unless you also include the document ID in the document itself.

Comment: "document ID might not be unique" answers the question. Thanks Frank!